# Force Terraform to apply pending changes on AWS Elasticache Redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache, terragrunt

I am attempting to change the node type of Elasticache from older generation (cache.t2.*) to newer generation (cache.t3.*) using Terraform.

Able to modify the node types successfully for all of Memcached instances via `terraform apply`, but unfortunately when I attempt to change the node type of Redis using `terraform apply` the command reaches completion in just ~30s and no change is applied.

To apply the node types change I have to login to web console and click individual Redis instance & click modify and apply the pending changes and wait for it to complete. This is manual work for me, I have to do this for 100 Redis instances.

Is it possible to force terraform to apply the pending changes for Redis on Elasticache?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to argument https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster#apply_immediately ?

Maybe another solution is to run a bash script with aws-cli `--apply-immediately` option https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/modify-cache-cluster.html

Comment: Some reason terraform apply_immediately was not working, but the below aws-cli command worked fine:

`aws-okta exec development -- aws --region us-west-2 elasticache modify-replication-group --replication-group-id "redis-clustername1" --apply-immediately`

Comment: Still not working as of 27th October. Although I have noticed if you terraform apply a change with 'apply immediately' within the maintenance period then it modifies it

Answer (score 1):

For me Terraform's apply immediately is not working so I am using the `aws-cli` to apply changes immediately.

The below shell commands will identify the pending changes on all clusters and submit apply immediately on each cluster instance.

```
PRFIL="profile1"
RGN="eu-west-1"

for cls in `aws-okta exec $PRFIL -- aws --region $RGN elasticache describe-cache-clusters | jq '.CacheClusters | .[] | select((.PendingModifiedValues | length ) > 0 and (.CacheClusterStatus!="modifying")) | .ReplicationGroupId ' | sort | uniq `  
  do
  echo $cls
  echo "aws-okta exec $PRFIL -- aws --region $RGN elasticache modify-replication-group --replication-group-id $cls --apply-immediately" | bash -vx | jq '.ReplicationGroup.Status'
done
```